# Is it possible to use Jasmine without Karma for testing Angular/Node based Nw.js apps?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, nw.js

I've read ton's of tutorials, but I must admit that this testing stuff is still very confusing to me. I have a Nw.js app which (of course) uses NodeJS and also Angular. I've installed the Jasmine test framework globally via npm and wrote an example test which starts with the following lines, and placed it in the **spec** sub-directory:

```
describe ( 'Test for my controller', function () {
    beforeEach ( module ('module_under_test') );

    ... and so on ...

});
```

When running the test by typing **jasmine** on the cmd line (from the root folder of the app), I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: module is not a function
```

I know that I have to include the Angular library somehow. But where? In a normal browser application, it is included in the HTML `<script>` tag, but I don't have this possibility. I also know that I could write a HTML file, which shows the Jasmine result page after tests have finished, but I would prefer to start Jasmine on the cmd line.

First I thought about adding the angular library to the "**helpers**" entry in **jasmine.json**. But it didn't work. The documentation of this file is unfortunately very poor. In the Angular documentation and tutorials it is always mentioned to use Karma. But my understanding is that Karma is only useful for testing with browsers, since it spawns an own webserver. This does not make sense in my case.

Would be great if somebody could give me a hint, thanks!

Comment: *But where?* - where did you include it before? Both angular and angular-mocks should be loaded, it doesn't really matter how. *but I would prefer to start Jasmine on the cmd line* - this is what Karma is for. I'd suggest to re-ask the question regarding Karma, since you're stuck at trying to implement its functionality.

Comment: Thanks estus. As said, in my Nw.js app the Angular library is included in the main HTML page and thus is available to the .js files. So, if I understand you right, there is no possibility to directly tell Jasmine to somehow include Angular (or maybe other libs as well), correct?

Comment: Jasmine isn't responsible for that. The thing that runs Jasmine is. A *test runner*. Which Karma is. Or HTML page in your case. You need to have another HTML file that is dedicated to testing. And load angular-mocks.js there in addition to angular.js. Or load it dynamically via JS at some point.